# Derivation explanation needed

Tags: textbook-and-exercises

I'm pretty new to the field. I was reading Preskill Ph219 [course notes](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph229/notes/chap1.pdf) and came across this. I am a bit confused about the derivation and wondered if someone can write down some skipped steps here.

[image]

Comment: please see https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Please edit the post to state explicitly what you don't find clear about the stated calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ is a function that takes in $x$ and outputs a single bit 0 or 1.

To start, if we assume that $f(x)$ returns 0, then the state is

$|x\rangle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$.

If instead, we assume the $f(x)$ returns 1, then the state is

$|x\rangle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1\rangle-|0\rangle)$.

But the only difference between these is a factor of -1!, so we can factor out $(-1)^{f(x)}$ which will give us the desired phase shift as a function of $f(x)$.